# Int'l tel input javascript library returns invalid input even if number is valid

Tags: javascript, intl-tel-input

I'm currently using https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input js library to validate my phone inputs. But unfortunately it always returns the `Invalid number` error even if the number is active and valid here in our country. Please see my code below for reference.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/int-tel-input/css/intlTelInput.min.css">
    <style>
        .hide { display: none; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" id="phone">
        <span id="valid-msg" class="hide">✓ Valid</span>
        <span id="error-msg" class="hide"></span>
    </div>
    
    <script src="assets/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/int-tel-input/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/controller.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**controller.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var input = document.querySelector("#phone"),
      errorMsg = document.querySelector("#error-msg"),
      validMsg = document.querySelector("#valid-msg");

    // here, the index maps to the error code returned from getValidationError - see readme
    var errorMap = ["Invalid number", "Invalid country code", "Too short", "Too long", "Invalid number"];

    // initialise plugin
    var iti = window.intlTelInput(input, {
        initialCountry: "PH",
        onlyCountries: ["ph"],
        separateDialCode: true,
        utilsScript: "assets/int-tel-input/js/utils.js"
    });

    var reset = function() {
      input.classList.remove("error");
      errorMsg.innerHTML = "";
      errorMsg.classList.add("hide");
      validMsg.classList.add("hide");
    };

    // on blur: validate
    input.addEventListener('blur', function() {
      reset();
      if (input.value.trim()) {
        if (iti.isValidNumber()) {
          validMsg.classList.remove("hide");
        } else {
          input.classList.add("error");
          var errorCode = iti.getValidationError();
          errorMsg.innerHTML = errorMap[errorCode];
          console.log(errorCode)
          errorMsg.classList.remove("hide");
        }
      }
    });

    // on keyup / change flag: reset
    input.addEventListener('change', reset);
    input.addEventListener('keyup', reset);

})
```

Reference:
https://intl-tel-input.com/node_modules/intl-tel-input/examples/gen/is-valid-number.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are importing the utils script properly:

```
    var input = document.querySelector('#whatsapp_number');
        iti = window.intlTelInput(input, {
            initialCountry: "ID",
            separateDialCode: true,
            utilsScript: "/assets/plugins/custom/intl-tel-input/js/utils.js" // make sure this script found
        });
```